# How to write a function for profit and loss percentage for N days in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, math

I am writing a function for profit and loss for N days and implementing it on pandas dataframe. But I'm going wrong in the condition which i'm giving to the code.

```
Date        Open Price High Price Low Price Last Price Close Price
2017-05-15  885.50     928.00     885.40     911.25     912.20
2017-05-16  908.20     909.00     890.20     894.00     894.70
2017-05-17  894.90     899.15     880.50     889.00     887.05
2017-05-18  888.00     917.90     865.20     866.15     871.35
2017-05-19  877.00     895.10     813.50     850.60     852.40
2017-06-01  802.00     817.95     794.00     803.40     803.70
2017-06-02  807.00     838.85     801.40     837.00     834.35
```

I have to find if there was profit or loss for each day. and later write a function in which based on a custom parameter N, the function will return profit or loss percentage for N days. 
This is what i have tried so far
{Note : Profit/Loss percentage between N days is the percentage change between the closing prices of the 2 days}

```py
def profit_loss_pct(N):
    df_n_days = df.tail(N)
    profit_loss_prcnt = ((df_n_days["Open Price"] - df_n_days["Close Price"])/df_n_days["Close Price"])
    if profit_loss_prcnt < 0:
        print("Loss: " + profit_loss_prcnt*100,"%")
    else:
        return print("Profit: " + profit_loss_prcnt*100,"%")

profit_loss_pct(20)
```

EDIT 1:
i tried the code my Francesco Zambolin

```
def profit_loss_pct(N):
    df_n_days = df.tail(N)
    profit_loss_prcnt = ((df_n_days["Open Price"] - df_n_days["Close Price"])/df_n_days["Close Price"])
    for n in range(N):
        if profit_loss_prcnt[n] < 0:
            print("Loss:", profit_loss_prcnt[n]*100,"%")
        else:
            print("Profit:", profit_loss_prcnt[n]*100,"%")
```

EDIT 2:

after trying this:

```
def profit_loss_pct(N):
    total_days = len(df['Profit/Loss'])
    calc_pnl = df['Profit/Loss'][total_days-N:].sum()
    if calc_pnl.iloc[N] < 0:
          print("Loss pct is: {:5.2f}%". format(calc_pnl.iloc[N]*100));
    else:
         print("Profit pct is : {:5.2f}%". format(calc_pnl.iloc[N]*100));
    return
```

i get the error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-ca9c4298a3c4> in <module>()
      1 #Average price and PNL pct for 1 week
      2 average_price(7)
----> 3 profit_loss_pct(7)
      4 print("")
      5 #Average price and PNL pct for 2 week

<ipython-input-20-6053bcd8e488> in profit_loss_pct(N)
     10     total_days = len(df['Profit/Loss'])
     11     calc_pnl = df['Profit/Loss'][total_days-N:].sum()
---> 12     if calc_pnl.iloc[N] < 0:
     13           print("Loss pct is: {:5.2f}%". format(calc_pnl.iloc[N]*100));
     14     else:

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

if its a series, it should locate the value right? but why is this not working?

Comment: `profit_loss_prcnt` would be a `Series`. You cannot treat it like a scalar with `if.`

Comment: so how shall i proceed further??

Answer (score 0):

Your profit_loss_prcnt is a series of N values. You can, for example put your if-statement in a for loop over the N values. When you encounter a negative pct your if will do the job.

N.B. You have a typo in print: you either pass profit_loss_prcnt as a string str(profit_loss_prcnt*100) so your +sign works or you put a comma like this:
print("Loss:", profit_loss_prcnt*100,"%")

Your function would be:

```
def profit_loss_pct(N):
    df_n_days = df.tail(N)
    profit_loss_prcnt = ((df_n_days["Open Price"] - df_n_days["Close Price"])/df_n_days["Close Price"])
    for n in range(N):
        if profit_loss_prcnt[n] < 0:
            print("Loss:", profit_loss_prcnt[n]*100,"%")
        else:
            print("Profit:", profit_loss_prcnt[n]*100,"%")
```

Comment: `18 profit_loss_pct(50)

---> 12         if profit_loss_prcnt[n] < 0:
     13             print("Loss:", profit_loss_prcnt[n]*100,"%")
     14         else:

KeyError: 0`

Comment: is there anyway i could do this differently? if so, how then?

Answer (score 0):

```
def profit_loss_pct(N):
    total_days = len(df['Profit/Loss'])
    calc_pnl = df['Profit/Loss'][total_days-N:].sum()
    if df["Profit/Loss"][N] < 0:
          print("Loss pct is: {:5.2f}%". format(df["Profit/Loss"][N]*100));
    else:
         print("Profit pct is : {:5.2f}%". format(df["Profit/Loss"][N]*100));
    return 

>>>Profit pct over  365 days is :  3.21%
```

i understood where i was going wrong, this worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

get dataframe

```
import pandas_datareader as web
df = web.data.get_data_yahoo('ibm', start='2019-01-01', end='2019-06-01')
df.head(3)

Date        High        Low          Open       Close       Volume                  
2019-01-02  115.980003  111.690002  112.010002  115.209999  4239900.0   
2019-01-03  114.879997  112.690002  114.529999  112.910004  4346700.0   
2019-01-04  117.489998  114.440002  114.910004  117.320000  4477800.0
```

> I have to find if there was profit or loss for each day

```
df['Profit/Loss'] = (df['Close'] - df['Close'].shift(1)) / df['Close']

df.head(3)

Date        High        Low         Open        Close       Volume   Profit/Loss                        
2019-01-02  115.980003  111.690002  112.010002  115.209999  4239900.0   NaN
2019-01-03  114.879997  112.690002  114.529999  112.910004  4346700.0   -0.020370
2019-01-04  117.489998  114.440002  114.910004  117.320000  4477800.0   0.037589
```

> later write a function in which based on a custom parameter N, the
>   function will return profit or loss percentage for N days

```
def getPL(N):
  total_days = len(df['Profit/Loss'])
  return df['Profit/Loss'][total_days-N:].sum()

getPL(30)

-0.09336249871304825
```

Answer (score 0):

**This function will do your work.**

```
def profit_loss(data,n):
    change = data['Close Price'].iloc[-n] - data['Close Price'].iloc[-1]
    per  = (change*100)/data['Close Price'].iloc[-n]
    return per
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
def plperct(N):
    tb3=tb.tail(N)
    t=((tb3['Close Price']-tb3['Prev Close'])/tb3['Prev Close'])*100
    return t
```